# Handling Errno::ETIMEDOUT exception in capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano, net-ssh

I am using a block to dynamically generate a list of servers I want to push code to. Occasionally a few of the machines are unreachable, resulting in a "Errno::ETIMEDOUT". This stop the entire deployment process. How do I rescue this and run some custom code using capistrano?

Comment: Hi Vinoth, interesting question. I took the liberty of sponsoring it on CodersClan. http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/213

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to wrap your server list generator with a try catch block.

```
begin
  # ... Get server list
rescue Errno::ETIMEDOUT
  # ... Handle cases when connection times out
end
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. I even tried wrapping the task itself or the commands within the task. Nothing seems to work.